# how to extract css and html from already opened page which has been changed and modifed locally

Tags: memory, extract, opera

i am faced with a huge problem. I have been developing a website since many days now. I have a style1.css which i use through dream weaver. today morning i was starting work on a new page and i by mistake linked an old style1.css from another website folder into my current HTML/JSP page(that i started work on today) and i continued everything. It got saved and the latest style1.css got replaced by the older one and got updated. This is screwed up eveything, and i dont have a backup because i never made such a blunder ever and the file that i linked was from an older backup. I didnt know. Now i have an old Reg.html(the proper one) page open in my Opera browser. What i want to do is copy the css and HTML from the browser itself from memory. Because if i view source and click on my linked CSS file, it shows the current(wrong one) and also the HTML source maybe wrong. I have replaced about 3-4 days of work, i cannot afford to rework, so if there any way i can extract html and css from an opened page from memory. (what i am saying is that if i refresh, my work is gone, so i havent refreshed it and carefully trying to extract out.) I tried recuva file recovery software locally, in my css folder, but it doesnt work. in windows previuos versions also there is nothing. In dreamweaver is there any backup mechanism from which i can restore it? I think my only option is to extract from opera. Is there any software or mechanism i can use to do that? or do i have to work again. The latter means that i have to do all the work again on multiple pages. Please help me! :(

Comment: If you have the correct one you want to keep online, you can just view , copy and paste from source back into dreamweaver.

Comment: but the css file linked to it is not showing i guess